# Validation attribute on model WebApi?

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api, model, attributes

I would like to know if it is possible to add a validation attribute to a property of the input model.
The property is an enum and my goal is to give a limitation of enumerative values to the property considered.

It's possible?

Here is what I would like to do:

```
 public enum EnumExample
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F,
    G
}
```

In the first model I would like to insert for property TypeClass only the values A,B,C

```
public class GetABC
{
    ***[Range (A,B,C)]***
    public EnumExample TypeClass { get; set; }
}
```

while I would like to insert for property TypeClass1 only the values E,F,G

```
public class GetEFG
{
    ***[Range (E,F,G)]***
    public EnumExample TypeClass1 { get; set; }
}
```

It's possible?

What attribute can be used?

Only with Regex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own custom attribute validator and perhaps validate the values that way?

Something along the lines of:

```
public class EnumValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly string[] _values;

        public EnumValidatorAttribute(params string[] values)
        {
            _values = values;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (_values.Contains(value))
                return ValidationResult.Success;

            return new ValidationResult("Not a valid Enum value");
        }
    }
```

Then use is like:

```
[EnumValidator("Value1", "Value2")]
public myEnum MyEnumProperty {get;set;}
```